# how to make my python telegram bot to send message at certain time every day?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to make a bot which will be able to notify users at a certain time every day. how can I make bot to send notification at certain time every day?

I've tried to use while loop but it s

```py
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def CalendarAnswer(c):
    Cid = c.message.chat.id
    if c.data == 'ShowTime':
        bot.send_message(Cid, timeToday)
    if c.data == 'ShowDate':
        bot.send_message(Cid, dateToday)
    if c.data == 'SetNotification':
        Ask = bot.send_message(Cid, 'Напиши мне время')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(Ask,SettingNotificationTime)
def SettingNotificationTime(message):
    NotificationTime = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "that's your time:" + NotificationTime)v
```

i don't have any idea of how can i solve my problem

Comment: How about at or cron?

Comment: what are u talking about?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [JobQueue](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.ext.jobqueue.html) from class telegram.ext

It has a function called run_daily.

```
run_daily(callback, time, days=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), context=None, name=None)
```

Here is an example:

```
def callback_alarm(context: telegram.ext.CallbackContext):
  bot.send_message(chat_id=id, text='Hi, This is a daily reminder')

def reminder(update,context):
   bot.send_message(chat_id = update.effective_chat.id , text='Daily reminder has been set! You\'ll get notified at 8 AM daily')
   context.job_queue.run_daily(callback_alarm, context=update.message.chat_id,days=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),time = time(hour = 10, minute = 10, second = 10))
```

This *run_daily* function calls the **callback_alarm** function daily at **10:10:10 AM**

Comment: How to ad this in updater, should we use mesaagehandler or commandhandler?

Answer (score 1):

For regularly scheduling batch tasks, you should you the system built-ins:

On Windows, it's the Task Scheduler, formerly a command called "at":

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-task-using-task-scheduler-command-prompt

> > On Windows 10, Task Scheduler is a tool that allows you to create and run virtually any task automatically. Typically, the system and
> >     certain apps use the scheduler to automate maintenance tasks (such as
> >     disk defragmentation, disk cleanup, and updates), but anyone can use
> >     it. With this experience, you can start applications, run commands,
> >     and execute scripts at a particular day and time, or you can also
> >     trigger tasks when a specific event occurs.
>
> Task Scheduler works by keeping tabs of the time and events on your
>   computer and executes the task as soon as the condition is met.
>
> Whether you're trying to use the Task Scheduler to run a task at a
>   specific time or when an event occurs, you can create a task in at
>   least two different ways using the basic and advanced settings.

Related to this is the "at" command:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313565/how-to-use-the-at-command-to-schedule-tasks

> The at command uses the following syntax:

```
at \\computername time /interactive | /every:date,... /next:date,... command
at \\computername id /delete | /delete/yes
```

On Linux, it's "cron":

https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux