# how to schedule a telegram bot to send a message?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to create a Telegram bot that sends a message at a specific time, 5:30pm. However, the ways a was trying are not correct.

I wanted to trigger send_message regarding to the time and without the necessity of the user to send any /command.

```
import telebot
import datetime

TOKEN = 'MyToken'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    message_id=message.chat.id
    bot.reply_to(message,"Welcome")


bot.polling()
```

Until now I was trying to add something like that, of course it is not python but kind of pseudocode just to explain:

```
if currenttime=17:30
 send_message(idchat, "mymessage")
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58375629/6714367

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to check your system time before sending a message, you could use the following code [[source]](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/current-time):

```py
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Current Time =", current_time)
```

To send a message you could use the following code [[source]](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/94889/telebot.TeleBot):

```
def test_send_message():
        text = 'CI Test Message'
        tb = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
        ret_msg = tb.send_message(CHAT_ID, text)
        assert ret_msg.message_id
```

To compare the time, you may use:

```
if current_time=='17:30:00':
    test_send_message()
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want but I don't know how to integrate it with the python API of Telegram

Comment: You might be looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48288124/how-to-send-message-in-specific-time-telegrambot

Answer (score 0):

You can use **schedule** python library.
First of all import the necessary modules

```
import schedule
import time
import telegram
```

Then you have to create a function that will repeat in every x time.
Here the bot will send me message in every 5 seconds.

```
TOKEN='your_token'
bot = telegram.Bot(token=TOKEN)
def job():
    bot.sendMessage(chat_id=<chat_id>, text="Hello")

schedule.every(5).seconds.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

For more informations about **schedule** [Read the documentation](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)